# How to add dropdown in video js control?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am creating video player using video js. I have to add dropdown in control bar to new line. How can I do this?

Comment: I refered documentation. But not found how to add control to new line. thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: What do you mean by new line?

Comment: I got the solution by my self. thanks